# Can somebody explain me this datetime result

Tags: r, posixct

I am puzzled with this result:

```
a = "2008-03-03 12:30:38"

#I convert to POSIXct and set the timezone
dt = as.POSIXct(a, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz='Europe/Paris')

dt
[1] "2008-03-03 12:30:38 CET"

unclass(dt)
[1] 1204543838
attr(,"tzone")
[1] "Europe/Paris"

#I want to come back to POSIXct    
as.POSIXct(unclass(dt), origin='1970-01-01', tz='Europe/Paris')
[1] "2008-03-03 11:30:38 CET"
```

I would have expected to get back the date-time `a`, what is wrong here ?

Comment: The origin is GMT, and therefore at 01:00 in CET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in `?as.POSIXct`, the origin is in `tz="GMT"`.

You can use `.POSIXct` instead:

```
.POSIXct(unclass(dt), tz='Europe/Paris')
# [1] "2008-03-03 12:30:38 CET"
```

Comment: sorry but what does it mean ? I indicated `tz` everywhere, do you mean that there is no way to achieve what I was testing ?

Comment: `.POSIXct(as.POSIXct(unclass(dt), origin='1970-01-01', tz='GMT'),tz='CET')
[1] "2008-03-03 12:30:38 CET"` I just got it !

Comment: It means the origin is _always_ in GMT when you call `as.POSIXct.numeric` and you can't change it.

Comment: Ok so why does `as.POSIXct` have a `tz` argument ?

Comment: but this is what was intended in `as.POSIXct(unclass(dt), origin='1970-01-01', tz='Europe/Paris')` that's what I do not understand

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the attribute:
    isdst
To see if there is some Daylight Savings conversion going on in there somewhere.
This page [from the R manual on Date-Time Classes](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html) may be useful